# Platform Initialize hangs on Hybris 6.3.0.25 which contains only platformbackoffice extension

Tags: initialization, sap-commerce-cloud

**Hybris:** 6.3.0.25

When initializing Hybris 6.3.0.25 with `platformbackoffice` extension, the initialization never finishes.

Is there a workaround to fixing this issue?

**STEPS TO REPLICATE:**

- Download and Extract ZIP file of Hybris 6.3.0.25
- In platform folder, do `ant all` using default settings
- In localextensions.xml, make sure `platformbackoffice` is the only extension
- In platform folder, do `ant initialize`
- Start Hybris
- Open HAC and do Platform Intialize

**NOTES:**

- Nothing is added in local.properties. So, Platform Initialize will use in-memory DB. However, the same issue also happens with mySQL 5.6.42.
- Issue also happens with Hybris 6.3.0.24
- The issue does not happen in Hybris 6.3.0.0-SNAPSHOT
- I am planning to upgrade from Hybris 6.3.0.0-SNAPSHOT to the latest 6.3, which would be 6.3.0.25 at the time of this writing. Before that, I also tested with 6.3.0.24 and the upgrade didn't go so well.

**ACTUAL RESULT:**

- Hybris hangs.

[image]

**EXPECTED RESULT:**

- Platform Initialize finishes successfully

**LOGS:**

- https://pastebin.com/Sx0223UM

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, only platformbackoffice can be running. You need more modules then it. I haven't got exact list, you can check dependencies in module config xml file (extensioninfo.xml). It is giving error about missing cockpit config with below message in your log file.

> [DefaultCockpitConfigurationService] Could not load cockpit configuration root element; creating new one

What is your aim for running only platformbackoffice?

Comment: Thanks for chiming in. If you looked at the attached logs in Pastebin, I also had that error. I would assume that if it had any dependencies, it would pull that in automatically.

Here's what's weird. If you initialize via ant, it finishes successfully. If you initialize via HAC, it hangs and gives you that error.

Additionally, I have another setup where localextensions contains a whole lot more extensions, including custom extensions. In 6.3.0.0-SNAPSHOT (Yes, very old!), I can initialize all those extensions successfully via HAC, but not in 6.3.0.25.

Comment: The purpose of this scenario is just to test if 6.3.0.25 can Platform Initialize or Platform Update via HAC successfully. Also, I'd assume that having Platform Backoffice alone should work, and at least allow you to create products via backoffice UI, even if other features are not available. i.e. It should give you minimum PCM functionality.

If not, what other extensions do you think I should add to resolve this DefaultCockpitConfigurationService issue?

Comment: I know there is only one company only using PCM module. But I haven't got information about configuration. Depencies tracking working only child to child not to parent and some modules java codes referencing other modules without dependencies information. For example product type not in platformbackoffice. Did you check path 25 has whole source? We generally paste patch source to snapshot.

Comment: A patch release, as defined by Hybris (in Hybris Help), is a complete release. The entire ZIP file is considered as "good". When I used that zip alone (without custom extensions) with "platformbackoffice" in my localextensions, Initialize via HAC would hang.

The Product type exists. I'm able to initialize completely via command-line, and I can start Hybris and open the Backoffice. But if I initialize it later in HAC, it hangs.